# How to make a two-line subtitle in Avisynth?

Tags: avisynth

Is it possible to show a subtitle on two lines?
I tried this code but "\n" doesn't work

```
BlankClip(width=640, height=360, length=25, fps=25, color=$FFFFFF)
Subtitle("123 \n ABC", size=100, x=320, y=290, align=2, text_color=$0000ff)
```

I also tried this:

```
Subtitle("123" + "\n" + "ABC", size=100, x=320, y=290, align=2, text_color=$0000ff)
```

It still doesn't work.
I am using Avisynth+ 3.7

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: using lsp (=Line Spacing Parameter)

```
BlankClip(width=640, height=360, length=25, fps=25, color=$FFFFFF)
Subtitle("123 \n ABC", size=100, x=320, y=240, align=5, lsp=-10, text_color=$0000ff)
```

http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Subtitle